# Website renders perfect on all browsers except chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rendering

I'm building a website [(here is the link only from the homepage)](http://kuki.im/apc). I created the homepage using Chrome as a browser on my desktop. Now I took my project on my MacbookPro Retina with 10.9.5 OSX installed to work from home. On chrome it doesn't render good (but on my desktops chrome is ok). I checked for errors in console but nothing. On Safari everything is good. Also on Firefox and IE 10-11. 
I reinstalled chrome, repaired permissions, I've checked my code for unclosed tags, disabled some scripts etc but nothing. It's very strange. I'm having the same version of Chrome in the office and in my mbp. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpkve.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was the `background-attachment: fixed`. It doesn't play well with Chrome as I read in the net.